# Pinning UITableViewCells programmatically to all sides

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created UITableViewCells programmatically but I can't seem to make the cells fit on all screen sizes. In order to do this, do I use NSLayoutConstraints or am I missing something else?

Thanks

Comment: If you created the cell programatically, then you also need to set the layout constraints for the objects inside the cell programatically.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is your problem, the description is quite vague, but the default width of UITableViewCell is fixed (320), and to change this you have to redefine the frame of the cell for you cell class.

one of the way to do this is to find the width of your screen and to define the frame of your cell accordingly (obviously it's supposed that UITableView.frame is something like (0, 0, screenWidth, height) ).

```
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    self.frame = CGRectMake(10, 0, screenWidth - 20, self.frame.height)
```

Comment: Thanks Lithium. Where in my code should I place this?

Comment: Where did you get screenWidth?

Comment: actually now I'm not sure that my way is the best (Rohit Kumar is right; it's not very good to work with screenWidth and screenHeight directly), but it's working.

Comment: so, what I did. I have an UITableView, and I created class for my cells. this part of code (overrided init) was from this class. 

screenWidth is easy.
    `let screenSize:CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    let screenHeight = screenSize.height
    let screenWidth = screenSize.width`

for using custom cells you have to register your class with UITableView:
    `tableView.registerClass(MyCellClass.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")`

and later in cellForRowAtIndexPath:
    `let cell =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCellClass`

Answer (score 0):

The default width of tableCell is the width of its container ie: tableView not fixed to 320.

If you created your cell programatically you can use Lithium's code to cover entire width of the screen except the padding.